# How does an optimized car battery charging system could be designed?

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging, automotive, rectifier, generator

To start, I saw a scooter electrics. In that implementation, after quite a weak (in my sense) generator it has some shunt linear regulator, that just dissipates overvoltage to heat. Oh god! Weak generator + such many losses + inability to carry electronics, I would never buy myself one! :)

Now consider I've bought some big car, and I am electricity geek, so I've somehow managed to install 480Ah*12V battery pack in it. I want to be able to run kind of welding, and have many electrical devices, but power consumers are not the case. Just appreciate it's somehow could be used, in a quite short time.

I feel that I should modify supply system in a first place. First step is ofc is buying a powerful generator, I'll accelerate slower, and would agree to waste some amount of engine power to charging, at its best! I heard car generators are 3-phase. Scooter weak stuff is 1-phase. But what's after? Generator is working at a quite random RPM, its rectified and voltage varies alot. What should I place after a generator between battery? Or *how to design extremely-heavy load car charging system*?

PS. Indeed a PC exists in that car. It could control and have to log voltage and current draw, so a subquestion is "how to measure current draw", when multiple batteries connected to some "distribution copper bar"? You typically dont want any bit of power loss, but have to measure aggregated current from all the batts.. but that's worth another question. You may just comment on that topic briefly, so that I could do my own research, and not flooding questions in here. Thanks!

Comment: i think that all of your ideas are just flowing into your post ... it makes the post too broad, especially since you asked multiple questions ... perhaps you could reduce your post to asking one specific question ... this one appears to be the most specific one `What should I place after a generator between battery?`

Comment: An alternator of any vehicle applies current feedback to the field winding to raise the voltage by coupling the rotor to the stator with this field at any RPM above 500 normally. Current rating depend on the size of the electrical loads at 14.2V and excess current  for charging. Currents < 100 A are common for small engines and Currents in large v8’s can be 150A or higher in big trucks must be passed by 6 large heat sunk diodes for the 3 phase bridge.

Answer (score 0):

In automotive charging systems the alternator output current is controlled by adjusting the alternator field current.  The alternator regulator senses the battery voltage and adjusts the field current to keep that voltage at a suitable level to keep the batteries charged.